# pass params from db onclick, set variables in JS and pass variables to a php function by ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I posted a question earlier but I couldn't get it to work because my code was wrong.  Like the title says, I'm pulling some data from a DB and echoing it in a div.  When clicked, I want to take THIS data and pass it to a javascript file, set the variables and send these variables to a php file to be inserted into a DB.  I want to do all this so the page does not refresh.  Here's my div:

```
echo "<div><a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='wish(".$title.", ".$link."); 
return false;'>Add to Wish List</a></div>";
```

The title and link are data pulled from a database.  JS script:

```
$(function() {
function wish(title, link){
var title = //how to set this to the title passed??
    var link = //how to set this to the link passed??
}
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "wish_list.php",
  data: title and link //what's the correct syntax to pass these two vars???
  success: function(){
    alert("Item added to your wish list");
}
});
});
```

And in PHP wish_list.php file I'll use:

```
if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['link'])){
   echo"<script>
     alert("variables passed");
   </script>";
}
```

So how far off am I?  What am I missing or is it all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are close but you just have to decide what data format to use, if you would like to use JSON you can use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in PHP and [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) in JavaScript.

### Passing variables to PHP and getting JSON from PHP

PHP:

```
$url = json_decode($_POST['url']); // You have a php array of the details now
var_dump($url);
```

JS:

```
var url = { 
    title: 'Home Page', 
    link: location.href
};

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "wish_list.php",
    data: JSON.stringify(url),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){ console.log(data); }
});
```

### Passing variables from PHP to JavaScript

The following is inspired by how Drupal does it. Include this **after** you include jQuery but **before** you include other scripts:

```
<script>
  var Globals = { 'settings': {}, 'somethingelse': {} };
  jQuery.extend(Globals.settings, {'phpVersion':'<?php print phpversion() ?>', link:'http://www.google.com', title:'Google'});
</script>
```

Then in JavaScript you can read and write to the settings:

```
// Add this device's window width
jQuery.extend(Globals.settings, {'deviceWidth':$(window).width()});

// Now print everything Global.settings has including the variable set by PHP
console.dir(Global.settings);

// Or get a specific variable:
console.log('This server is running PHP ' + Globals.settings.phpVersion);
```

Comment: Can you explain the var url?  What are you setting the title and link to?  Is that something I have to change?  Sorry but I do not understand

Comment: Rather than pass many variables to the PHP script, particularly if they are grouped like those ones it is cleaner to put them into an array. The values of title and link are just an example. It seems to me on second reading that you actually want to pass php variables to javascript is that correct? In that case all the code using ajax is wrong on this page.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I want to pass php variables from my div to javascript and then pass them to a wish_list.php file where they will be inserted into the database.  If you think the code is wrong, what's the right way to do this?

Comment: Updated with an example of passing php variables to js

Answer (score 0):

Youre already using jquery so first lets clean up your html:

```
echo "<div><a class=\"wishable\" href=\"#\" data-wishlist-title=\"$title\" data-wishlist-link=\"$link\">Add to Wish List</a></div>"
```

I removed all the js from the html. If youre using jQuery theres no real reason to inline the functionality on to the html. In order to get access to the data we want I encoded it in data attributes which can be accessed with `jQuery.attr` or `jQuery.data`. I also added a class of `wishable` so that we can attach a click handler to all the links.

So no lets hook up the old inline function you had:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click.wishable', 'a.wishable', function (e) {
         var $this = $(this), // the <a />
             title = $this.data('whishlistTitle'), // pull the title from the data attr
             link = $this.data('wishlistLink');  // pull the link from the data attribute

         e.preventDefault(); // prevent default link handling

         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "wish_list.php",
           data: {"title": title, "link": link },
           success: function(){
             alert("Item added to your wish list");
           }
         });         
    });
});
```

Now how we get the link and title:

```
title = $this.data('whishlistTitle')
link = $this.data('wishlistLink')
```

When using `jQuery.data` with data attributes there is a conversion for the attribute name. The `data-` prefix is dropped, and then the rest is transformed from hyphenated to camelCase. Additionally the value will be converted to a native javascript type. This is really improtant with numeric strings that arent really numbers (like 0 padded product SKUs for example) but for your example its not going to matter. This does however make `data` slower than `attr`.

We can also use `jQuery.attr` instead but need to use the full attribute name:

```
title = $this.attr('data-whishlist-title')
link = $this.attr('data-wishlist-link')
```

Heres a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hyFXM/1/

For testing you can just echo back what you passed in and alert that. So the `jQuery.ajax` looks like:

```
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "wish_list.php",
           data: {"title": title, "link": link },
           success: function(text){
             alert(text);
           }
         });
```

And then you php would look like:

```
if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['link'])){
   echo 'SUCCESS - $_POST[\'title\'] =' . $_POST['title'] . ' $_POST[\'link\'] = '. $_POST['link'];
} else {
   echo 'FAIL WHALE!!!!!!';
}
```

Comment: This is what I have in my wish_list.php file:
<?php if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['link'])){
  echo "<script>alert('It worked');</script>";}?>
I just want to see it work before I write the mysqli function but I still get nothing.  Shouldn't I get two alert messages if everything works?

Comment: Well I just got a FAIL WHALE...even though it was funny, I'm still frustrated as hell :(

Comment: perhaps try doing `print_r($_POST);` before, after or instead of the fail whale. Also inspect the request with the Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools network panel and make sure the data is sending. Also make sure the variables echoed out correctly in your HTML.